# Zooming on a particular image inside a stackpanel consits of ten images

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7.1

I have a scrollviewer with horizontal stackpanel having 10 images as children. I need to perform zooming on a particular image which is in view when start the pinch gesture. Is it possible to achieve that. I tried to get the image in a separate layout when start the pinch but it makes the user to start the pinch twice.So kindly help me to get that

Answer (score 0):

Do a click event on the image, then popup a window with a semi transparent background and an image control. Then apply pinch events to zoom and mouse move events to pan.

something like this article:

http://codecopy.wordpress.com/2011/12/15/wp7-pinch-and-pan-zoom-an-image/